# Wifi 6E not recognised on newly built Z690 PC with Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS installed

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, iwlwifi

noob here!

Even by reading all that I could on stuff relating to my issue, I am still struggling to get my wifi working.  Here are some details:

## Hardware:

MSI Pro Z690-A Wifi motherboard (Intel Wifi 6E onboard module)

## Software:

Freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04.3

## Output from terminal:

```
uname -r
5.13.0-27-generic

lsmod | grep iwlwifi
iwlwifi               372736  0
cfg80211              888832  1 iwlwifi

sudo lshw -class network
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 11
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:6491c000-6491ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 03
       serial: d8:bb:c1:8f:39:7c
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igc driverversion=5.13.0-27-generic duplex=full firmware=1079:8770 ip=192.168.50.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 memory:64600000-646fffff memory:64700000-64703fff

dmesg | grep iwl
[    2.005460] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.008773] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.008918] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-62.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.008928] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-61.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.009121] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-60.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.009132] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.009251] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-58.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.009339] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-57.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.009348] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.009356] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-55.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.009365] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-54.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.009372] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-53.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.009381] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-52.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.009390] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-51.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.009399] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.009408] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.009418] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-48.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.009427] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-47.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.009435] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-46.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.009445] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-45.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.009453] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-44.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.009462] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-43.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.009472] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-42.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.009480] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-41.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.009489] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-40.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.009499] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-39.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.009500] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: no suitable firmware found!
[    2.009502] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-39
[    2.009504] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-63
[    2.009505] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
[12790.858270] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858277] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-62.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858282] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-61.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858286] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-60.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858290] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858295] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-58.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858299] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-57.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858304] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858309] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-55.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858314] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-54.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858318] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-53.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858322] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-52.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858327] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-51.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858331] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858335] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858339] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-48.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858344] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-47.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858348] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-46.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858353] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-45.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858357] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-44.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858362] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-43.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858366] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-42.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858370] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-41.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858374] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-40.ucode failed with error -2
[12790.858378] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-39.ucode failed with error -2
**[12790.858379] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: no suitable firmware found!**
[12790.858381] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-39
[12790.858381] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-63
[12790.858382] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

I can see that it complains about not finding suitable firmware, but I am at my wits end as to knowing what to do further...
I've tried copying the latest firmware into the /lib/firmware dir and doing the modprobe cmd to no avail.
I've also renamed the file iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm in /lib/firmware (not sure if I need to rename iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm as well - tried it but it did not seem to make any difference) and rebooted with no luck.

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I am out of my depth here and really want to get this beast up and running.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. just as a by-note - the Bluetooth and Ethernet seems to work fine

Comment: Even in Ubuntu 21.10, the only firmware in /lib/firmware is iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-64.ucode, so your older 20.04 iwlwifi driver is looking for too old firmware. Either install 21.10, or you can try installing `backport-iwlwifi-dkms`. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema, HUGE thank you!!!  - installing backport-iwlwifi-dkms did the trick!!!  I've got wifi working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments...

Intel AX210

Either install Ubuntu 21.10, or you can try installing `backport-iwlwifi-dkms`.

**Update #1:**

Installing `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` solved the problem.