# Wireless Network not showing with iwlwifi card

Tags: drivers, apt, kernel, iwlwifi

I have a iwlwifi card built into my [motherboard](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B09KJG7YB8/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&th=1). I can see the card, though it displays as a ethernet card?

```
hutber@hutber:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7af0] (rev 11)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0094]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

However when checking if is working correctly it certainly does complain about the firmware:

```
hutber@hutber:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    9.236975] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    9.238500] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.238598] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-62.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.238694] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-61.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.238710] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-60.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.238725] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.238738] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-58.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.238750] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-57.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.238902] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.238991] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-55.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.239005] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-54.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.239017] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-53.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.239031] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-52.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.239044] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-51.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.239148] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.239161] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.239173] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-48.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.239186] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-47.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.239197] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-46.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.239212] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-45.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.239225] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-44.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.239234] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-43.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.239246] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-42.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.239258] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-41.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.239269] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-40.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.239281] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-39.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.239282] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: no suitable firmware found!
[    9.239300] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-39
[    9.239319] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-63
[    9.239338] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

So I then [tried to install](https://askubuntu.com/a/1390315/115908) `sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms`  but was slapped by the computer dogs for shooting in the dark:

```
hutber@hutber:~$ sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
[sudo] password for hutber:  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.4.0-105 linux-headers-5.4.0-105-generic linux-image-5.4.0-105-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-105-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-105-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed
  backport-iwlwifi-dkms
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 1,568 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 backport-iwlwifi-dkms all 8324-0ubuntu3~20.04.4 [1,568 kB]
Fetched 1,568 kB in 1s (2,130 kB/s)                
Selecting previously unselected package backport-iwlwifi-dkms.
(Reading database ... 509974 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../backport-iwlwifi-dkms_8324-0ubuntu3~20.04.4_all.deb ...
Unpacking backport-iwlwifi-dkms (8324-0ubuntu3~20.04.4) ...
Setting up backport-iwlwifi-dkms (8324-0ubuntu3~20.04.4) ...
Loading new backport-iwlwifi-8324 DKMS files...
Building for 5.13.0-39-generic
Building initial module for 5.13.0-39-generic
Error!  The /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/8324/5.13.0-39-generic/x86_64/dkms.conf for module backport-iwlwifi includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
Skipped.
```

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.13.0-39

Comment: Please try Will's answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356118/ax210-wifi-not-working-on-ubuntu21-04

Comment: This video refers to ubuntu when fixing WiFi issues and is worth watching

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you're running with the latest 20.04 kernel 5.13.0-39-generic, and you don't have the proper `iwlwifi-so*.ucode` firmware files for your wifi card, and the `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` that you tried to install won't work with your current kernel.

The required `iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode` firmware doesn't seem to exist in any of the `linux-firmware` blobs.

`backport-iwlwifi-dkms_8324-0ubuntu3~20.04.4_all.deb` won't install on the latest 20.04 kernel 5.13.0-39-generic without modifications. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400376/ubuntu-20-04-lts-intel-wi-fi-6e-ax210-driver-doesnt-work-after-update/1400548#1400548). But that won't work anyway.

Remove the older `backport-iwlwifi` module that you tried to install...

`sudo dkms remove backport-iwlwifi/8324 -k 5.13.0-39-generic`

You'll need to get the impish version of `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/backport-iwlwifi-dkms) and the latest `linux-firmware` from [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/snapshot/linux-firmware-20220310.tar.gz).

Install the two files this way...

`sudo dpkg -i backport-iwlwifi-dkms_9340-0ubuntu4_all.deb`

Expand `linux-firmware-20220310.tar.gz` and `sudo cp` the iwlwifi-so* files to /lib/firmware.

`reboot`

Retest wifi.

Comment: Holy smoke it worked.... And here I have spent hours doing it!!

Comment: @JamieHutber Glad it worked for you!

Comment: @heynnema Big thanks to you! It worked for me as well.

Comment: @heynnema thank you very much, worked for me also