# Unable to connect to wifi ubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.13.0-39-generic Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, kernel

For some reason I could use the wifi connection just fine yesterday and now (next) day I can't seem to connect to any wireless point. I'm not sure but it's possible I did an update yesterday of the kernel which might have resulted in this.

I've tried to fix the problem following the method described in [Wireless Network not showing with iwlwifi card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401173/wireless-network-not-showing-with-iwlwifi-card) since I got the same error:

> Error!  The /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/8324/5.13.0-39-generic/x86_64/dkms.conf for module backport-iwlwifi includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
> does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
> Skipped.

when trying to reinstall 'backport-iwlwifi-dkms', it seems this hasn't solved it. Although trying the remove command before I tried to install the version '9340-0ubuntu4' resulted in the error

> sudo dkms remove backport-iwlwifi/8324 -k 5.13.0-39-generic
> resulted in the error
> Error! There are no instances of module: backport-iwlwifi
> 8324 located in the DKMS tree.

I tried the proposed solution anyway since I've got no idea what else to do but it didn't seem to have solved the problem.
My kernel version is 5.13.0-39-generic. Some info:

```
lspci -v:

Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at b4518000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

In the `dmesg | grep iwl` command iwl is red, in the `lsmod |grep iwlwifi` command iwlwifi is red also. Not sure what to do now, could it be hardware related?

Sorry if the layout isn't all that great, first time making a thread.

EDIT:

```
dkms status:
backport-iwlwifi, 9340, 5.13.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 510.60.02, 5.13.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 510.60.02, 5.13.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed

lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A5:
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] [8086:a370] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] [8086:0034]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:a368] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller [17aa:3803]


sudo dmesg | grep wlp:

[    3.326214] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
[   35.709806] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d
[   35.711359] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d (try 1/3)
[   35.751294] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   35.752450] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d (try 1/3)
[   35.759034] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d (capab=0x111 status=0 aid=1)
[   35.761378] wlp0s20f3: associated
[   35.833590] wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d
[   37.812251] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[   48.361892] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd
[   48.364277] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd (try 1/3)
[   48.499460] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   48.500479] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd (try 1/3)
[   48.506409] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd (capab=0x111 status=0 aid=3)
[   48.509309] wlp0s20f3: associated
[   48.515944] wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 18 (18 - 0) dBm as advertised by 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd
[   50.584825] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[   57.277573] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f
[   57.279940] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f (try 1/3)
[   57.323236] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   57.324699] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f (try 1/3)
[   57.331870] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f (capab=0x111 status=0 aid=1)
[   57.336255] wlp0s20f3: associated
[   57.337919] wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f
[   59.459178] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[   71.533577] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf
[   71.541686] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf (try 1/3)
[   71.587817] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   71.588425] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf (try 1/3)
[   71.595372] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf (capab=0x111 status=0 aid=13)
[   71.598713] wlp0s20f3: associated
[   71.661363] wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf
[   73.656907] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[   77.029098] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf
[   77.034343] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf (try 1/3)
[   77.074009] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   77.076517] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf (try 1/3)
[   77.082569] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf (capab=0x111 status=0 aid=4)
[   77.085397] wlp0s20f3: associated
[   77.186704] wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 18 (18 - 0) dBm as advertised by 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf
[   79.275562] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[   90.981417] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8f
[   90.989202] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8f (try 1/3)
[   91.032703] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   91.040947] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8f (try 1/3)
[   91.144515] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8f (try 2/3)
[   91.248496] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8f (try 3/3)
[   91.352730] wlp0s20f3: association with 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8f timed out
[   91.518366] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cf
[   91.524685] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cf (try 1/3)
[   91.666764] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cf (try 2/3)
[   91.773367] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cf (try 3/3)
[   91.875706] wlp0s20f3: authentication with 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cf timed out
[   92.014851] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:28:44:ef
[   92.021287] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:28:44:ef (try 1/3)
[   92.063993] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   92.064473] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:28:44:ef (try 1/3)
[   92.269150] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:28:44:ef (try 2/3)
[   92.374550] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:28:44:ef (try 3/3)
[   92.475986] wlp0s20f3: association with 2c:4f:52:28:44:ef timed out
[   94.803524] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f
[   94.809855] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f (try 1/3)
[   94.853931] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   94.856484] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f (try 1/3)
[   94.960510] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f (try 2/3)
[   95.064490] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f (try 3/3)
[   95.168513] wlp0s20f3: association with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f timed out
[   96.257568] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf
[   96.264002] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf (try 1/3)
[   96.303519] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   96.308501] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf (try 1/3)
[   96.412494] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf (try 2/3)
[   96.516507] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf (try 3/3)
[   96.621001] wlp0s20f3: association with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf timed out
[   97.678147] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf
[   97.684549] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf (try 1/3)
[   97.725578] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   97.728485] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf (try 1/3)
[   97.832755] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf (try 2/3)
[   97.936765] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf (try 3/3)
[   98.040684] wlp0s20f3: association with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf timed out
[   99.083233] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8f
[   99.089583] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8f (try 1/3)
[   99.131633] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   99.132459] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8f (try 1/3)
[   99.236993] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8f (try 2/3)
[   99.340741] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8f (try 3/3)
[   99.444497] wlp0s20f3: association with 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8f timed out
[  101.721761] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cf
[  101.728100] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cf (try 1/3)
[  101.771861] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  101.772467] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cf (try 1/3)
[  101.880865] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cf (try 2/3)
[  101.984927] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cf (try 3/3)
[  102.015052] wlp0s20f3: aborting association with 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cf by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  102.061675] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cf
[  102.067916] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cf (try 1/3)
[  102.108269] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  102.112812] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cf (try 1/3)
[  102.232829] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cf (try 2/3)
[  102.336464] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cf (try 3/3)
[  102.440808] wlp0s20f3: association with 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cf timed out
[  103.492295] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:28:44:ef
[  103.498834] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:28:44:ef (try 1/3)
[  103.645978] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:28:44:ef (try 2/3)
[  103.708436] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  103.712732] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:28:44:ef (try 1/3)
[  103.851085] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:28:44:ef (try 2/3)
[  103.952699] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:28:44:ef (try 3/3)
[  104.059848] wlp0s20f3: association with 2c:4f:52:28:44:ef timed out
[  107.281350] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f
[  107.285265] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f (try 1/3)
[  107.324910] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  107.328477] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f (try 1/3)
[  107.432745] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f (try 2/3)
[  107.536749] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f (try 3/3)
[  107.640463] wlp0s20f3: association with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f timed out
[  117.787095] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf
[  117.790718] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf (try 1/3)
[  117.830329] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  117.832503] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf (try 1/3)
[  117.936500] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf (try 2/3)
[  118.040459] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf (try 3/3)
[  118.144474] wlp0s20f3: association with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf timed out
[  131.665401] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d
[  131.667393] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d (try 1/3)
[  131.708912] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  131.712429] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d (try 1/3)
[  131.718405] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d (capab=0x111 status=0 aid=1)
[  131.720652] wlp0s20f3: associated
[  131.782854] wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d
[  133.837869] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  154.855639] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd
[  154.857632] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd (try 1/3)
[  154.992505] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  154.996517] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd (try 1/3)
[  155.002173] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd (capab=0x111 status=0 aid=2)
[  155.004472] wlp0s20f3: associated
[  155.320466] wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 18 (18 - 0) dBm as advertised by 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd
[  157.057822] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  180.558251] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd
[  180.565909] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd (try 1/3)
[  180.606900] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  180.607332] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd (try 1/3)
[  180.613555] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd (capab=0x111 status=0 aid=13)
[  180.616833] wlp0s20f3: associated
[  180.720384] wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd
[  182.661845] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

EDIT II (I was using usb tethering through smarthphone and had a vpn active when doing these commands, just to note should it be relevant):

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i iwl:
[    3.175195] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 0
[    3.175200] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 1
[    3.175202] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 2
[    3.175203] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 3
[    3.175205] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 4
[    3.175206] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 6
[    3.175207] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 8
[    3.175209] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 9
[    3.175210] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 10
[    3.175212] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 11
[    3.175213] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 15
[    3.175214] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 16
[    3.175216] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 18
[    3.175217] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 19
[    3.175219] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 20
[    3.175220] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 21
[    3.175221] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 28
[    3.175513] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.4d093a30.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.255700] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz, REV=0x318
[    3.304726] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 58:a0:23:7e:26:ab
[    3.372674] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    3.375689] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0

sudo dmesg | grep -i wlp:
[    3.375689] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
[   21.604404] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d
[   21.605749] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d (try 1/3)
[   21.646009] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   21.648268] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d (try 1/3)
[   21.654963] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d (capab=0x111 status=0 aid=3)
[   21.656954] wlp0s20f3: associated
[   21.724337] wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d
[   23.710573] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[   35.085873] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd
[   35.087751] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd (try 1/3)
[   35.223365] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   35.224311] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd (try 1/3)
[   35.237370] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd (capab=0x111 status=0 aid=14)
[   35.240465] wlp0s20f3: associated
[   35.342840] wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd
[   37.288076] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[   45.303982] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd
[   45.307741] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd (try 1/3)
[   45.347207] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   45.348702] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd (try 1/3)
[   45.354321] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd (capab=0x111 status=0 aid=3)
[   45.356713] wlp0s20f3: associated
[   45.381401] wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 18 (18 - 0) dBm as advertised by 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd
[   47.397389] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[   59.299015] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8d
[   59.306089] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8d (try 1/3)
[   59.358827] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   59.362578] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8d (try 1/3)
[   59.466860] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8d (try 2/3)
[   59.571009] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8d (try 3/3)
[   59.678960] wlp0s20f3: association with 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8d timed out
[   59.839863] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:09:79:cd
[   59.846247] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:09:79:cd (try 1/3)
[   59.887020] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   59.890363] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:09:79:cd (try 1/3)
[   59.994708] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:09:79:cd (try 2/3)
[   60.098247] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:09:79:cd (try 3/3)
[   60.214154] wlp0s20f3: association with 2c:4f:52:09:79:cd timed out
[   60.380114] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cd
[   60.386369] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cd (try 1/3)
[   60.426885] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   60.430147] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cd (try 1/3)
[   60.534088] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cd (try 2/3)
[   60.638454] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cd (try 3/3)
[   60.742422] wlp0s20f3: association with 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cd timed out
[   60.885540] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:28:44:ed
[   60.891953] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:28:44:ed (try 1/3)
[   60.996438] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   61.002367] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:28:44:ed (try 1/3)
[   61.138909] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:28:44:ed (try 2/3)
[   61.242681] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:28:44:ed (try 3/3)
[   61.344623] wlp0s20f3: association with 2c:4f:52:28:44:ed timed out
[   63.657559] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d
[   63.663837] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d (try 1/3)
[   63.709406] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   63.717103] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d (try 1/3)
[   63.821097] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d (try 2/3)
[   63.925472] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d (try 3/3)
[   64.029466] wlp0s20f3: association with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d timed out
[   65.128656] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd
[   65.135165] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd (try 1/3)
[   65.175930] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   65.176738] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd (try 1/3)
[   65.280978] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd (try 2/3)
[   65.385254] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd (try 3/3)
[   65.493213] wlp0s20f3: association with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd timed out
[   66.571727] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd
[   66.579192] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd (try 1/3)
[   66.619064] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   66.620626] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd (try 1/3)
[   66.725022] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd (try 2/3)
[   66.828988] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd (try 3/3)
[   66.936964] wlp0s20f3: association with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cd timed out
[   67.998411] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8d
[   68.001337] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8d (try 1/3)
[   68.040628] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   68.044232] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8d (try 1/3)
[   68.152200] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8d (try 2/3)
[   68.260140] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8d (try 3/3)
[   68.364142] wlp0s20f3: association with 2c:4f:52:4d:e1:8d timed out
[   68.981965] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cd
[   68.987789] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cd (try 1/3)
[   69.027580] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   69.036190] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cd (try 1/3)
[   69.139980] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cd (try 2/3)
[   69.243593] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cd (try 3/3)
[   69.347591] wlp0s20f3: association with 2c:4f:52:52:8b:cd timed out
[   70.415220] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:09:79:cd
[   70.421544] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:09:79:cd (try 1/3)
[   70.462179] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   70.467392] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:09:79:cd (try 1/3)
[   70.571318] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:09:79:cd (try 2/3)
[   70.675399] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:09:79:cd (try 3/3)
[   70.783100] wlp0s20f3: association with 2c:4f:52:09:79:cd timed out
[   71.826850] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:28:44:ed
[   71.833225] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:28:44:ed (try 1/3)
[   71.877176] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   71.882221] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:28:44:ed (try 1/3)
[   72.018681] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:28:44:ed (try 2/3)
[   72.190436] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:28:44:ed (try 3/3)
[   72.293882] wlp0s20f3: association with 2c:4f:52:28:44:ed timed out
[   74.506898] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d
[   74.513098] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d (try 1/3)
[   74.554464] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   74.561490] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d (try 1/3)
[   74.664999] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d (try 2/3)
[   74.768954] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d (try 3/3)
[   74.873316] wlp0s20f3: association with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8d timed out
[   85.021960] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd
[   85.028171] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd (try 1/3)
[   85.069011] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   85.069610] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd (try 1/3)
[   85.173619] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd (try 2/3)
[   85.277593] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd (try 3/3)
[   85.385569] wlp0s20f3: association with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cd timed out
[   97.223199] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f
[   97.227017] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f (try 1/3)
[   97.266732] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[   97.267343] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f (try 1/3)
[   97.274814] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f (capab=0x111 status=0 aid=2)
[   97.278078] wlp0s20f3: associated
[   97.296601] wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f
[   99.343180] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  124.169643] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf
[  124.171447] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf (try 1/3)
[  124.307709] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  124.308478] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf (try 1/3)
[  124.314067] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf (capab=0x111 status=0 aid=3)
[  124.316165] wlp0s20f3: associated
[  124.332833] wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 18 (18 - 0) dBm as advertised by 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf
[  126.375059] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  149.070182] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf
[  149.077177] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf (try 1/3)
[  149.130951] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  149.133101] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf (try 1/3)
[  149.204753] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf (capab=0x111 status=0 aid=14)
[  149.208234] wlp0s20f3: associated
[  149.212965] wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf
[  151.303944] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  346.894194] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with f0:9a:51:0c:41:cb
[  346.901912] wlp0s20f3: send auth to f0:9a:51:0c:41:cb (try 1/3)
[  346.944249] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  346.944669] wlp0s20f3: associate with f0:9a:51:0c:41:cb (try 1/3)
[  346.965480] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from f0:9a:51:0c:41:cb (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  346.968179] wlp0s20f3: associated
[  350.984121] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticated from f0:9a:51:0c:41:cb (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[  382.528536] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with f0:9a:51:0c:41:cb
[  382.534887] wlp0s20f3: send auth to f0:9a:51:0c:41:cb (try 1/3)
[  382.580214] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  382.584656] wlp0s20f3: associate with f0:9a:51:0c:41:cb (try 1/3)
[  382.604706] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from f0:9a:51:0c:41:cb (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
[  382.609768] wlp0s20f3: associated
[  382.741134] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp0s20f3: link becomes ready
[  410.486093] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticated from f0:9a:51:0c:41:cb (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  411.902471] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with f0:9a:51:0c:41:cb
[  411.908121] wlp0s20f3: send auth to f0:9a:51:0c:41:cb (try 1/3)
[  412.049509] wlp0s20f3: send auth to f0:9a:51:0c:41:cb (try 2/3)
[  412.158624] wlp0s20f3: send auth to f0:9a:51:0c:41:cb (try 3/3)
[  412.264391] wlp0s20f3: authentication with f0:9a:51:0c:41:cb timed out
[  920.222515] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f
[  920.228333] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f (try 1/3)
[  920.268568] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  920.271011] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f (try 1/3)
[  920.277220] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f (capab=0x111 status=0 aid=2)
[  920.279934] wlp0s20f3: associated
[  920.293183] wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f
[  922.339271] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 6c:ab:05:a9:1a:8f by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  948.140350] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf
[  948.146096] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf (try 1/3)
[  948.189386] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  948.190321] wlp0s20f3: associate with 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf (try 1/3)
[  948.197221] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf (capab=0x111 status=0 aid=3)
[  948.200177] wlp0s20f3: associated
[  948.253372] wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 18 (18 - 0) dBm as advertised by 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf
[  950.305776] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 2c:4f:52:09:58:cf by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  972.774879] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf
[  972.782577] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf (try 1/3)
[  972.826976] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  972.829808] wlp0s20f3: associate with 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf (try 1/3)
[  972.836577] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf (capab=0x111 status=0 aid=14)
[  972.839175] wlp0s20f3: associated
[  972.930045] wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf
[  974.894251] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 6c:ab:05:c0:2b:cf by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

Comment: The items in RED are the search strings that you used. Just info. Your problem has occurred because of the new 5.13 kernel. Edit your question and show me `dkms status` and `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A5`. Then, via the GRUB menu, boot back to a 5.11 kernel and see if it starts to work again. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: We'd also like to see: `sudo dmesg | grep wlp` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @heynnema  I've put the output under "EDIT:". I'll try/check the 5.11 kernel in a bit.

Comment: I'm not sure that you need the backport driver. Do `modinfo iwlwifi | grep -i alias | grep 0034` and you should get one hit, and then `sudo dkms remove backport-iwlwifi/9340 -k 5.13.0-39-generic`, reboot, then redo the modinfo command, and confirm that you still get one hit. Also, it looks like you've tried to connect to three different access points, correct? Are they on the same router? Have you rebooted the router yet?

Comment: @heynnema Doing the modinfo command gave one hit, removing the backport , rebooting and redoing the command still gave one hit. The 3 different acces points are wifi provided by the residence where I'm at (student) so rebooting the router won't be possible for me.

Comment: Yes, as I thought, you don't need the backport driver. I'll be interested to see if it works with the 5.11 kernel. You can also try booting to a Ubuntu Live USB version 22.04 beta and see if it works. I'm suspecting a 5.13 kernel problem.

Comment: @heynnema apparently I didn't have the 5.11 kernel installed so I searched how to install an older one. I've downloaded 'mainline' and installed 5.11.20 but that seemed to lag really hard so I'm not sure if I need to install a different version of 5.11 or try another way to get the 5.11 kernel.

Comment: The mainline program should be ok, and although 5.11.20 may have lagged, did the wifi work again? Go ahead and try the Ubuntu Live 22.04 beta. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema The wifi didn't work in 15.11.20 it seemed the same problem. I currently don't have an usb drive with me to check the Ubuntu Live 22.04 beta.

Comment: Perhaps also relevant maybe is that I'm able to connect using my phone to the network and other students don't seem to have a problem connecting to the network. The problem should lie with ubuntu somewhere.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo dmesg | grep -i iwl` and `sudo dmesg | grep -i wlp`.

Comment: @heynnema I've added it, but I had to remove some earlier output due to 30k limit. I do have the full text still saved if necessary

Comment: That's fine. Thanks. What security is set in your wifi connection profile?

Comment: @heynnema WPA and WPA2 Enterprise, authentication is PEAP with CA certificate. Inner authentication is MSCHAPv2. But these settings normally didn't change.

Comment: Can I assume that you can connect to other wifi networks not associated with the student network? Did you get these security settings and CA from the IT folks? Please SHOW PASSWORD and confirm your Username and Password. Retype Password even if it looks correct. Retest.

Comment: @heynnema Where I'm at I can't test other networks, I've tried to make hotspot with my smarthphone and that connects, tomorrow I'll be at home and I'll see if I can connect with that. Username and password are correct. Security settings were from site of IT folks... nevermind seems the problem is solved. They seemed to randomly change the certificate yesterday evening without informing anyone. Now its  USERTrust RSA Certification Authority instead of DigiCert Assured ID Root CA. Unbelievable... Big thank you for the help!

Comment: @Mike Great news! I put together a quick answer. Please feel free to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

**Wireless Security configuration is:**

WPA and WPA2 Enterprise, authentication is PEAP with CA certificate. Inner authentication is MSCHAPv2.

[image]

**Solution was:**

They (IT) seemed to randomly change the CA certificate yesterday evening without informing anyone. Now its USERTrust RSA Certification Authority instead of DigiCert Assured ID Root CA.