# Ubuntu 20.04 - wireless network showing DISABLED

Tags: drivers, 20.04, network-manager, iwlwifi

My laptop's WiFi has stopped working after an update. I can turn it ON/OFF from settings but it has subtitle "unavailable" and a loader at visible networks. I have tried almost everything internet could suggest but no luck.

Moreover I had WiFi adapter it works for few days and then after another update it also stops working and it doesn't even shows up in the menu let alone to connect to WiFi.

Am using (I don't have dual boot)

- **OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS**
- **Kernel: 5.13.0-40-generic**
- **System: HP ProBook 450-G8 11-Gen**

##### Things I have found and tried so far.

- I can't see any driver in "Additional Drivers", download from "Main Server"
- I have tried disabling secure boot via `sudo mokutil --disable-validation`,rebooting and then changing "Change Secure Boot State" to disabled.
- I tried updating package `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` via "Synaptic Package Manager" but option "Mark For Upgrade" is disabled.
- I get this after running `lshw -c network`

```
*-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
```

- Running `nmcli` shows

```
wlp0s20f3: unavailable
        "Intel Wi-Fi"
        wifi (iwlwifi), 64:BC:58:69:xx:xx, sw disabled, hw, mtu 1500
```

- This `rfkill list` shows

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Running `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` shows

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0f0] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0034]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

`cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` shows

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

`dmesg | grep iwl` shows around 2500+ lines see [here](https://pastebin.com/Lmi76Age)

As recommeneded by @Pilot6 running `sudo apt remove backport-iwlwifi-dkms` shows

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'backport-iwlwifi-dkms' is not installed, so not removed
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfwupdplugin1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

@Pilot6 recommeneded to get latest mainline kernel

I got these files
[image: latest kernel files]

from ([https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.17.4/amd64/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.17.4/amd64/))
[image]

Got below error (see full response [here](https://pastebin.com/AzneNXv3)) after running `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-5.17.4-051704-generic:
 linux-headers-5.17.4-051704-generic depends on libc6 (>= 2.34); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.31-0ubuntu9.7.
 linux-headers-5.17.4-051704-generic depends on libssl3 (>= 3.0.0~~alpha1); however:
  Package libssl3 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-5.17.4-051704-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-unsigned-5.17.4-051704-generic (5.17.4-051704.202204200842) ...
I: /boot/vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to vmlinuz-5.17.0-051700-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img.old is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.17.0-051700-generic
I: /boot/vmlinuz is now a symlink to vmlinuz-5.17.4-051704-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.17.4-051704-generic
Setting up linux-modules-5.17.4-051704-generic (5.17.4-051704.202204200842) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-unsigned-5.17.4-051704-generic (5.17.4-051704.202204200842) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.17.4-051704-generic
   ...done.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Check the asked output at the bottom.

Comment: All looks good. Please add output of `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: @Pilot6 See the update. I have suspicion it might be something related to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf `

Comment: You have a kernel crash. `blacklist.conf` is unrelated. It looks like a kernel bug.

Comment: @Pilot6 So what are your suggestions to fix this, if it is fixable ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135807/discussion-between-daniyal-nasir-and-pilot6).

Comment: Report a bug and try another kernel.

Comment: @Pilot6 Should I try this solution to try another Kernel ? https://askubuntu.com/a/1401184/1147244

Comment: I suggest removing all backports. Remove it completely. It may work on this kernel.

Comment: Am sorry, am fairly new to ubuntu, when you say "remove all backports" Am understanding you meant removing "iwlwifi driver backport in DKMS format" from synaptic package manager right ? I've already done that and restart, no luck.

Comment: @Pilot6 Can you tell which commands should I run from [this](https://installlion.com/ubuntu/precise/main/l/linux-backports-modules-headers-precise-generic/uninstall/index.html) (if any) to remove backports

Comment: `sudo apt remove backport-iwlwifi-dkms`

Comment: @Pilot6 See the update at the bottom of the question, and yes I think you're right because initially my wifi was working.

Comment: Now reboot and see if it works. It isn't installed.

Comment: @Pilot6 Rebooted still showing wifi unavailable.

Comment: Try the latest mainline kernel.

Comment: @Pilot6 Am following up this tutorial [here](https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/#install-manually)

Comment: @Pilot6 I followed the above tutorial, got errors but reboot the system anyway. Please guide.

Comment: my colleague found the same issue on [the intel forums](https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/Linux-Intel-AC-9560-iwlwifi-fails-on-kernels-above-5-10/m-p/1377826#M41506) it appears the wrong driver is installed the hp probook has 2 variants a i5 version and a i7 version. The i5 version has a Intel AC 9560 wifi chip while [the i7 version has a Intel Corp. Wi-Fi 6 AX201](https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/Linux-Intel-AC-9560-iwlwifi-fails-on-kernels-above-5-10/m-p/1377826#M41506). So presumably we should be able to fix it by installing the driver for intel AC 9560

Comment: Well, I have Ci5 and have AX201 chip.

Comment: @DaniyalNasir i just found a solution/workaround i'll post it below, maybe it works for you

Comment: Well I have re-installed OS (Ubuntu 21) and been using Wifi-adapter for wireless network connectivity. If someone tried your solution and it worked for them. I'll accept your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A workaround for this would be to downgrade your kernel to anything 5.10 and below. Anything above 5.10 does not work with this wifi card's latest firmware.

I have the same configuration on a ProBook 450 G8 running Ubuntu 22.04.
Kernel 5.10.115.

Had the same issue on the first day, but been working happily with wifi after that.

To downgrade the kernel I used a tool called Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer.

Install with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa

sudo apt update

sudo apt install mainline
```

[image: Ubuntu Mainline Installer]

You can then use the tool to look for any 5.10 kernel version you desire, and install it.

Then reboot and make sure to select Advanced Options for Ubuntu in the GRUB menu before loading into the OS, in order to select the older 5.10 kernel.

After doing so, your wifi should already be detected and working.

If you so desire, you can delete / uninstall the newer 5.13 kernel.

I will note that downgrading the wifi card's firmware would also work in this case, without having to downgrade the kernel. But I found downgrading the kernel to be quick and painfree.

**EDIT**

At the time of writing, it appears that kernel 6.2+ addressed this issue and this WiFi card will work right out of the box so long as you are on 6.2+.

Answer (score 1):

i have found the same issue on a HP Probook 450 G8 with an intel wireless-AC 9560 chip, the following steps allowed me to workaround the issue

1. run `journalctl --system|grep "loaded firmware version"`
   this will print a bunch of lines with the actual firmware version that is   is loading. if you replace `grep "loaded firmware version"` with `grep iwlwifi` you see the relevant logs
   it should look like this:

```
Jun 13 07:11:57 <hostname> kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 55.d9698065.0 <firmware-name>.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
```

where  is the actual hostname of your computer and  is the name of the firmware being loaded

2. check in `/lib/firmware` for the loaded firmware version, it will like start with `iwlwifi-<firmware-name>` where  is the name found in step 1
3. move the loaded firmware out of `/lib/firmware`
4. run `modprobe -r iwlwifi && modprobe iwlwifi`
5. check `lshw -C network`
6. if step 6 no longer show `DISABLED` it should now work, if not repeat step 1-5 untill it no longer says `DISABLED`

according [this intel forum post](https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/Linux-Intel-AC-9560-iwlwifi-fails-on-kernels-above-5-10/m-p/1377826#M41506) `QuZ-a0-jf-b0-59.ucode` should work. In my case it didn't work so i also moved it out of the `/lib/firmware` directory, `QuZ-a0-jf-b0-55.ucode` appears to work for me on kernel 5.15